# C# Get Value from ID when ID changes Slightly

Tags: c#, automation, webbrowser-control, steam

I am trying to get value from an ID that changes slightly every time.

For example I have this :

```
<img id="economy_item_#######_item_icon" alt="Dual Berettas | Colony">
```

I am trying to retrieve "Dual Berettas | Colony" but where I have put the #'s is a number that changes every time. How can I achieve this?

Any and all help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Try a regex with the pattern [0-9]*

Answer (score 0):

You may use jQuery Attribute Contains feature.
https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/

Like this:

```
var txt = $("img[id*='economy_item_']").attr('alt');
```